# Parallel code with Task.Factory slower than linear

Tags: .net, f#, parallel-processing

I am playing with parallel programming and F#. I created a function that integrates a 1-variable function, and then I tried to make it parallel in two different ways:

```
module Quadrature = 

    let Integrate (f: double -> double) (x1: double) (x2: double) (samples: int64) =
        let step = (x2 - x1) / (double samples)
        let samplePoints = seq {x1 + step .. step .. x2 - step}
        let sum = samplePoints |> Seq.map (fun x -> f x) |> Seq.sum
        let sum = sum + ((f x1) + (f x2)) / 2.0
        step * sum

    let IntegrateWithStep (f: double -> double) (x1: double) (x2: double) (step: double) =
        let samples = (x2 - x1) / step |> round |> int64
        Integrate f x1 x2 samples

    let IntegrateWithTasks (f: double -> double) (x1: double) (x2: double) (samples: int64) (tasks: int) =
        let step = (x2 - x1) / (double samples)
        let samplesPerTask = ceil <| (double samples) / (double tasks)
        let interval = step * samplesPerTask
        let intervals = 
            seq { 
                for i in 0 .. (tasks - 1) do
                    let lowerBound = x1 + (double i) * interval
                    let upperBound = min (lowerBound + interval) x2  
                    yield (lowerBound, upperBound)
                }
        let tasks = intervals 
                    |> Seq.map (fun (a, b) -> Task.Factory.StartNew(fun () -> IntegrateWithStep f a b step))
        tasks |> Seq.map (fun t -> t.Result) |> Seq.sum

    let IntegrateParallel (f: double -> double) (x1: double) (x2: double) (samples: int64) (tasks: int) =
        let step = (x2 - x1) / (double samples)
        let samplesPerTask = ceil <| (double samples) / (double tasks)
        let interval = step * samplesPerTask
        let intervals = 
               [| for i in 0 .. (tasks - 1) do
                    let lowerBound = x1 + (double i) * interval
                    let upperBound = min (lowerBound + interval) x2  
                    yield (lowerBound, upperBound) |]
        intervals |> Array.Parallel.map (fun (a, b) -> IntegrateWithStep f a b step)
                  |> Array.sum
```

I run this code with the following input on a machine with 4 cores:

```
let f = (fun x -> - 1.0 + 2.0 * x - 3.0 * x * x + 4.0 * x * x * x ) 
let x1, x2 = 0.0, 1.0
let samples = 100000000L
let tasks = 100
```

However, the method with the task factory is always slightly slower than the linear one, while the one with the Parallel.map gives me a good speed up.

I have tried varying the number of tasks from thousands down to the number of cores but the implementation with the Task.Factory is always slower than the linear one. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that sequences are lazily loaded. Here is the first time the task gets started:

```
tasks |> Seq.map (fun t -> t.Result) |> Seq.sum
```

And you are starting them sequentially and blocking each one for their result (when calling `t.Result`. You'll want to save the list of tasks as an array, and then call `.WaitAll` before collecting the results to ensure they all get started in parallel.

Try:

```
let tasks = intervals 
            |> Seq.map (fun (a, b) -> Task.Factory.StartNew(fun () -> IntegrateWithStep f a b step))
            |> Array.ofSeq

tasks.WaitAll()
```

Comment: I modified this line to `tasks |> Seq.toArray |> Array.map (fun t -> t.Result) |> Array.sum` and it gives me a speed up now. Thanks!